# WordPress 3.9 - need a function to get Custom Post Type name to auto-fill Category in Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, dashboard

I have created several Custom Post Types in the Dashboard and I would like to auto-fill the Category name with the name of the Custom Post Type so the user doesn't have to remember to check the correct box when they add a new post.

So for example here are the Custom Post Types and their corresponding Category names:
News (id of Category 'News' is 5)
Events (id of Category 'Events' is 12)
Reports (id of Category 'Reports' is 8)
Videos (id of Category 'Videos' is 9)

This works. It will automatically check the 'News' Category box
`wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(5));`

I just need a way to determine which Custom Post Type I am in when Add New Post is selected.  Something like this should work but it doesn't.

```
function set_my_categories($post_type){   
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( 'post_type' );
    $post_name = $post_type ->labels->singular_name;  
    switch( $post_name )
    {
        case 'News':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(5));    
        break;    
        case 'Events':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(12));   
        break;    
        case 'Reports':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(8));    
        break;    
        case 'Videos':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, array(9));    
        break;              
    }
  }
  add_action('save_post', 'set_my_categories');
```

Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, in case anyone else needs to do this:

`function set_my_categories($post_id){
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    switch( $post_type ){
        case 'News':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array(5));
        break;
        case 'Events':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array(12));
        break;
        case 'Reports':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array(8));
        break;
        case 'Videos':
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array(9));
        break;
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'set_my_categories');`

Answer (score 0):

You call a function on a hook save_post, but you do not pass any variables to it. And your function needs to have a $post_type.

You should take a look at do_action() from wordpress codex :) It can pass args into functions :)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help me.  I need an example of how to code this.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not place to find answers "out of the box" - you need to work a bit, not to wait until someone give you code for copy-paste... :/

Comment: Most of the answers I see on stackoverflow are "out of the box" answers. Thanks anyway.